# Visual Editor renaming a variable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

In a .Designer file I have a `DataGridViewCellStyle`:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStylePhoto = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
this.photoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStylePhoto;
```

Whenever I change something, not related to this at all, in the Visual Editor, it insists on renaming this like so:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
this.photoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```

Why? How can I prevent this?

Comment: they tell us in summary "Required method for Designer support - do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor." are you editing something in designer.cs and doing something else in [design] ?

Comment: You can not prevent it.

Comment: @Amit: It happens either way. Editing directly in the source code or using the Visual Editor in [Design]

Comment: Why not change it in the normal code-behind file instead? That's never overwritten, unlike the designer which is meant to be regenerated every single time.

Comment: @Alejandro Then you will lose design-time support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a .Designer file I have a `DataGridViewCellStyle` ... Whenever I change something, not related to this at all, in the Visual
>   Editor, it insists on renaming ...

***Why?***

Whenever you change anything in your form designer, the whole content for `InitializeComponent` method will be regenerated again. This is how Windows Forms designer works.

For all implementations of `IComponent`, the name of the variable in the generated code will be the same as the name of the component.

***How can I prevent this?***

There is *no easy way* to keep variable name of `DataGridViewCellStyle`, because it's not an implementation of `IComponent` and designer doesn't store any information about its name and the name for the variable is generated on the fly.

Comment: There are some solutions to change the behavior of the designer when code generation, including *Registring a new `CodeDomeSerializer`*. For more information you can take a look at [Customizing Code Generation in the .NET Framework Visual Designers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx). But in action, as I mentioned, there is no easy way to prevent that behavior without changing a couple of things.

Comment: To me it seems to be [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you should not have any dependency to that name, anyway I provided answers to your questions, however you may don't like the answer ;)

Comment: The problem here isn't about depending on the name. The problem is that it clutters up version control history, making the real changes more difficult to see, when VS insists on mucking about with this. Or alternatively - manual labour before each commit to remove the nonsense changes using the diff viewer.